# How can I set a loop to pick words in a sentence?

Tags: java

**Objective:** To create a function which takes a single String argument. The string is then evaluated and words in the String are reversed.

The **output** desired:

Ex:  Hello World!
 --  olleH !dlroW

****Question***:* is how do I set up a loop so that I can separate the words from the sentence?
I am using a scanner to get the input from the user in the form of a String object.

Comment: What about a StringTokenizer?

Comment: You should do more research before asking. I'm not saying it's a bad question, it's just that you have no code, and the splitting part is easy (after researching)

Comment: I agree with @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ ... for someone who starts the question off with praise for the community, I expected a question that wasn't regularly asked and didn't have such an easy answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String source = "Hello World";

for (String part : source.split(" ")) {
    System.out.print(new StringBuilder(part).reverse().toString());
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Output:

olleH dlroW

**Notes:** Commenters have correctly pointed out a few things that I thought I should mention here. This example will append an extra space to the end of the result. It also assumes your words are separated by a single space each and your sentence contains no punctuation.

Credits: @William Brendel

Comment: Although it's even better to trust the word boundary `\b` rather than only looking at space.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans can you explain please why it is better to use `\b` than space ? What's the real difference ?

Comment: `\b` is the word boundary regex class. It sits between words and interpunction like spaces, commas, full stops, quote symbols, etc. Just splitting on " " means you end up with tokens like "word." and "this:" etc, which aren't words. They're words with punctuation attached to them.

Answer (score 1):

Separating words is easy: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

```
String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
```

would result in `words` containing each word delimited by the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
for (String s : str.split(" ")) {
    stack.push(new StringBuilder(s).toString());
}
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.print(stack.pop() + " ");
}
```

This specifically pushes it onto the stack and then pops it to reverse it.

I took some of your code E. Doroskevic, sorry!